# Invalid Pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I recently learned about pointers, and have been working hard to really understand them. However, I have run into trouble. For class we had to write a function that would double an array x amount of times. I was able to write the function without any real problems, but I'm trying to implement it into an actual code and I continue to get invalid pointer errors. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *ArrayDoubling(int inputArray[], int initialSize, int numberToDouble);

int main(){
    int arr[2] = {0,1};
    int array_size = 2;
    int number = 3;

    ArrayDoubling(arr, array_size, number);
}

int *ArrayDoubling(int inputArray[], int initialSize, int numberToDouble){
    for(int i=0;i<numberToDouble;i++){
        int *array2 = new int[initialSize*2];
        for(int i=0;i<initialSize;i++){
            array2[i] = inputArray[i];
        array2[i+initialSize] = inputArray[i]*2;
        }
        initialSize = initialSize*2;
        delete []inputArray;
        inputArray = array2;
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

So what exactly is causing the problem, and how can I fix it? Also not sure if this will actually print the output of the Array, but I'm also trying to get that to happen. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: `numberToDouble` has nothing to do with the number of elements in the array, so why is it being used to control the array index?

Comment: Also, `ArrayDoubling()` deletes the `inputArray` argument, but the array being passed in was not allocated with the `new[]` operator so that's not going to work.

Comment: you are calling `delete[]` on the array declared as `int arr[2]`  . This is not permitted, you can only `delete[]` things that were `new[]`'d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ArrayDoubling` function calls `delete[]` on the `inputArray` argument. But you pass a pointer to an automatic array when you call it in `main`. Calling `delete[]` with a pointer that you didn't get from `new[]` has undefined behaviour.

To fix it, only use the function with dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: Or better yet, do not reallocate arrays.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I'm mainly confused because in class we were supposed to write `ArrayDoubling` and then the autograder would kind of take care of the rest. I got assignment right, at this point I'm just trying to figure out how to implement `arrayDoubling` in an actual code. Though from what I've read it seems like the code shouldn't have worked out after all.

Comment: @JoshuaLucero as I said, what you did has undefined behaviour. A program that has UB is not required to *not work*. The auto grader probably just checks the result, not that the program happened to get the result by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is looping by the number of times to double, not the size of the array. For inputs where the size of the array is less than the number of times to double, you will be accessing out of range indices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your intension is, but I think your second for loop should look like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<initialSize;i++)
```

Comment: Wow not sure how I messed that up :/ That definitely had something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your code is this line: `delete []inputArray;`

`inputArray` was originally declared as `int arr[2] = {0,1};` which should not be deleted.  You can only delete variables which were created using keyword `new`.

Broadly speaking, your program is going to need to look something like this.  Note that `new[]` happens *outside* of the population loops in `ArrayRepeat` so it is only called once and similarly `delete[]` will only be called once, on the same pointer that was created through `new[]`.

```
// dynamically allocate an array which contains the first `N` elements of 
//   `array` repeated `repeats` times.
int * ArrayRepeat (int * array, size_t N, int repeats) {
  int * result = new int[N * repeats];
  assert(result); // Error check

  // Loops to populate result goes here

  return result;
}

int main (void) {
  int arr[] = {0, 1};
  int * repeated = ArrayRepeat(arr, 2, 3);

  // Print the result
  for (int i = 0; i < 2 * 3; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", repeated[i]);
  }

  delete[] (repeated);

  return 0;
}
```